# RestKit XML Response to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I am new to RestKit and I am using 0.20.

I have a situation in which I make a call to retrieve and XML file.  The XML file contains one or more XML tags with a value similar to the following:

```
<Configuration>
  <CustomParm1>value1</CustomParm1>
  <SomeUnknownKey>anotherValue</SomeUnknownKey>
  <AnotherUnknownKey>yetAnotherValue</AnotherUnknownKey>
</Configuration>
```

The tag names are unknown to me before making the call.  I just need the XML to come back in a dictionary with each tag name as the key and the related value as the value in the dictionary.

I have setup the object manager and place the call as follows:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com"]];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/xml"];

[manager getObjectsAtPath:@"/somepath/somefile.xml" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog (@"failure: operation: %@ \n\nerror: %@", operation, error);
}];
```

I get the following response:

> error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0xce67120 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://someurl.com/somefile.xml, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http://someurl.com/somefile.xml', which failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://someurl.com/somefile.xml, NSUnderlyingError=0xce6c950 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."}

All of the mapping examples I have seen I must know what the tag name is to complete the mapping.

Is there a way I can simply get the results back in a dictionary without knowing the tag names for mapping?